# Stop hadoop/EMR/AWS creating S3 paths with _$folder$ extensions

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, emr

Running spark jobs on EMR with output written directly to S3. I've noticed that each S3 directory path (e.g. `/the/s3/path`) contains a flag file called `/the/s3/path_$folder$`. This is causing issues reloading the data with spark (it's parquet and spark is complaining about extra files, etc).

How can I stop AWS/whatever it is from creating this flag? It used to happen with hadoop jobs too so I don't think it's spark (although that uses hadoop FS stuff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, yes I used to get these folders as well, but they no longer appear... I suspect it is because I have made these changes to the `hadoopConfiguration`:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class","org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
```

Aside from committing output directly to `S3`, these settings prevent creation of the metadata files, which apparently are of no real use anyway and simply takes up a lot of time to create.

I haven't verified that these settings will make the difference, but I strongly suspect that they do. I can check it one of these days, unless you beat me to it ;)

EDIT:

The `DirectOuputCommitter` is no longer available in Spark 2.x. The way to avoid the temporary writes to S3 in Spark 2.x is to add this setting to your `Spark Conf`:

```
spark.conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
```

(Note that it is no longer set on the `hadoopConfiguration`). This will, however, *not* get rid of the `_$folder$` folders. I have yet to work out how to disable them in Spark 2.x...

Comment: Thanks. I'd already got one of these settings but I'll try the others.

Comment: It seems that the DirectParquetOutputCommitter removes the _$folder$ flags while still keeping the _SUCCESS files which is exactly what I wanted.  Thanks

Comment: It appears that this no longer works in spark 2.0 see http://dev.sortable.com/spark-directparquetoutputcommitter/

Comment: @Thomas Luechtefeld I've made an update to my answer